# Custom options not showing Up in front-end Magento Community Edition

Tags: php, magento

I wrote a script for importing products in Magento community edition 1.5.10 from CSV file. The products are displaying fine in both front end and backend

The problem is the Product custom options(size and Color). It is not displaying in the front end. But it is displaying properly in admin.

When I edit the same product in adminpanel and saving without modifying anything, then its showing up fine in front end.

Please help me to figure out this problem

Thanks in advance

Selva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had the same problem with the custom option. Then i found out the solution after a long search in the database. You just forget to insert the values  in  "catalog_product_entity_varchar"  table.
For custom option we need to insert 4 records in the  "catalog_product_entity_varchar"  table.
After inserting the table it works well.. Hope it will helps you..
Thanks
Rajamani.

Comment: which 4 records you forgot to insert ??

Comment: Your answer is not informative, you haven't explained how did you inserted records into those 4 tables, from csv (or from coding customization, if so mention your full code here) ? In fact how did you solved your issue ? Provide detailed and explanatory answer.

Comment: Inserting data in the db is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

This almost always means that you've forgotten to add data to a necessary table, very likely an indexing table. Magento often clones the same data over to several tables to use for fast lookups.

Does your script import using objects, or does it write direct SQL queries to enter the data? Try reindexing everything on the site first, hopefully that will fix it. If  not, you'll need to spelunk in the DB to find the table that you are failing to enter data for.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the Magento caches and re-indexing.

I Hope custom option will display

Answer (score 0):

For me it was fixed by setting the has_options attribute to 1 - from catalog_product_entity table. Also make sure that the options_container attribute have the value 'container2' for products with custom options - this attribute is found in catalog_product_entity_varchar.